# QtSQL - QMYSQL driver not loaded (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtsql

I want to access a SQL database via `PyQt4` on Ubuntu. I already installed `apt-get install python-qt4-sql` but when I add a Database like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtSql

appcore = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QMYSQL')
db.setHostName('localhost')
db.setDatabaseName('database1')
db.setUserName('root')
db.setPassword('root')

if db.open() == False:
    print 'fail'
```

I get the error

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

How can I load the driver `QMYSQL`?

Comment: I want to connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that I need this driver. But anyway can you explain why it always returns `True`? I don't even have SQLite so it should return `False`, doesn't it? And yes I had a look at this question and I already did `apt-get install python-qt4-sql` but I get the error anyway when using `QMYSQL`.

Comment: SQLite would just open a new database file if there is none of the given name. Also there is no user management in SQLite, so there are no errors either. Maybe you need to install some other MySQL client libraries that are not added as dependencies. I once had a similar issue with PostgeSQL...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could fix the problem by installing `apt-get install libqt4-sql-mysql`.