# Set up hostname for remote server pyqt

Tags: postgresql, pyqt

I have made a postgres database in my computer. (Linux Mint 17)
Then, I have made a front end script for manage it in **pyqt**. In this script I set up the host name with localhost, like that:

```
self.conexion=QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
self.conexion.setHostName('localhost')
self.conexion.setPort(5432)
...........
```

It works without problems.

Now, I have installed the database in other computer into a local lan, with Windows 10.
I have no problem if I connect it from my Linux PC trough PgAdminIII, QGIS (is a spacial database) or psql. The ip of server is 192.168.1.102 in my local lan.

But I can't connect trough my script. I only have changed the hostname:

```
self.conexion=QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
self.conexion.setHostName('192.168.1.102')
self.conexion.setPort(5432)
.........................
```

but it doesn't work.
¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. I want to apologize because it was a mistake from me.
I hadn't installed **libqt4-sql-psql driver**  (similar question here: [QtSQL - QMYSQL driver not loaded (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792955/qtsql-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-ubuntu))

My mistake is because I format the Linux PC and I didn't remember those library

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the [`listen_addresses`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) in your config so that it will accept connections from other ip addresses.  It's pretty typical to set it to `*` for your type of application.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not the problem. As I said, I can connect from this PC with pgAdmin, psql and QGIS, setting the ip of the server like 192.168.1.102. Anyway I have read the postgresql.conf and "listen_addresses" is setting '*'